# Inspecting generalized attributes with libclang

Tags: c++, clang, abstract-syntax-tree, libclang

I would like to parse generalized attributes of class member functions in the following example:

```
class Foo
{
public:
    void foo [[interesting]] ();
    void bar ();
};
```

Using the libclang C API, I would like to distinguish between `foo` and `bar` (and know that `foo` has the `interesting` attribute) in the source. Is this possible? I have a hard time finding examples or documentation that explains the concepts used in the API (I've found a reference, but that's kind of hard to use when the concepts are not explained).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

While I was unable to find the generalized attributes in the AST (it seems they are dropped when or before constructing the AST, not after it), I did find a workaround.

There is an `annotate` clang attribute in the following form:

```
__attribute__((annotate("something")))
```

With a macro I could get a reasonable syntax and an annotation which is visible in the AST:

```
#define INTERESTING __attribute__((annotate("interesting")))

class Foo
{
public:
    INTERESTING void foo();
    void bar();
};
```

The attribute will be the child of the method node, with its display_name being the annotation string. A possible AST dump:

```
 <CursorKind.TRANSLATION_UNIT>
  "test.h"
{
  __builtin_va_list <CursorKind.TYPEDEF_DECL>
    "__builtin_va_list"
  type_info <CursorKind.CLASS_DECL>
    "type_info"
  Foo <CursorKind.CLASS_DECL>
    "Foo"
  {
     <CursorKind.CXX_ACCESS_SPEC_DECL>
      ""
    foo <CursorKind.CXX_METHOD>
      "foo()"
    {
       <CursorKind.ANNOTATE_ATTR>
        "interesting"
    }
    bar <CursorKind.CXX_METHOD>
      "bar()"
  }
}
```

It produces the same output with `void foo INTERESTING ();` too.

Answer (score 2):

Something like the following `first_attr` function will fetch the cursor of the first attribute of the passed cursor if it exists, or a null cursor if it doesn't (untested code... caveat lector)

```
CXChildVisitResult attr_visit(CXCursor cursor, CXCursor parent, CXClientData data) {
    if (clang_isAttribute(cursor)) {
        *data = cursor;
        return CXChildVisit_Break;
    }
    return CXChildVisit_Continue;
}

CXCursor first_attr(const CXCursor& c) {
    CXCursor attr;
    unsigned visit_result = clang_visitChildren(c, attr_visit, &attr);
    if (!visit_result) // attribute not found
        attr = clang_getNullCursor();
    return attr;
}
```

As for finding which specific attribute a cursor `a` represents, the result of `clang_getCursorKind(a)` can help, but the only attributes exposed are:

```
CXCursor_IBActionAttr
CXCursor_IBOutletAttr
CXCursor_IBOutletCollectionAttr
CXCursor_CXXFinalAttr
CXCursor_CXXOverrideAttr
CXCursor_AnnotateAttr
CXCursor_AsmLabelAttr
```

Everything else will be a `CXCursor_UnexposedAttr` and the only way I can think of to get the text of it is to examine `clang_getCursorExtent(a)` (i.e., read the source code; cf. `clang_tokenize`). In the case of annotations, the specific annotation used is available through `clang_getCursorDisplayName`.

Comment: I tried doing this with the python bindings to prototype the code, but the attribute was not visible in the AST at all (not as an unexposed attribute even). A `noreturn` attribute did appear in my AST dump when I added it.